# Hook for csv export view - flag exported items

Tags: hooks, importing-exporting

I am using [Views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) to export view with exposed filter, is there any hook or another way to run an action over these filtered items?

My goal: set "flag" (boolean field) for these exported items so I will know, they have been exported.

Answer (score 0):

Views Data Export isn't transactional and so if you're looking for something, you'd likely need to wrap up Views Data export with your own code that loops over the results and sets the flag then.

Comment: Could you please point me to the right section of module's code, where I can get these results?